# python post each csv row in x number of urls

Tags: python

i have code that post every row from csv file to each url from urls file.

i want to post each row from csv file to x urls in urls file for example:

if i set x to 10 so each row will post in 10 urls

row 1 in 0-10 urls

row 2 in 11-20 urls

row 3 in 21-30 urls

my code:

```
    urls_file = open('C:\\urls.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    for url in urls_file:
            try:
                with open('mycsv.csv', "r", encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
                    csv_reader = reader(csvfile)
                    header = next(csv_reader)
                    if header != None:
                        for row in csv_reader:
```

Comment: It’s not really clear to me what you want your code to do. Can you maybe give a (small) example of the input and  the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach with [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) function (which allows to extract a slice of specified length):

```
import itertools    
import csv

with open('test.csv', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile,\
        open('urls.txt') as urls_f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    if header is not None:
        for row in csv_reader:
            # here is an iterator of 10 records (urls)
            next_10_urls = itertools.islice(urls_f, 10)
            # continue your logic here
```

---

`next_10_urls` - is an iterator of subsequent 10 urls from `urls.txt`; can be converted to list with `list(itertools.islice(urls_f, 10))`. So you can proceed with mapping the current `row` to those respective urls.